# Arithmetics with decimal numbers

Tags: decimal-expansion

Let's suppose that

$$10,a+15,ba +15,3 = 2\times (20, ab)$$

where numbers are in their decimal representation, and so $ab$ and $ba$ are two digit numbers. Is there a straightforward way to evaluate $a\times b$? One approach is to write down

$$10+\frac{a}{10}+15+\frac{10b+a}{100}+15+\frac{3}{10} = 2\times (20+\frac{10a+b}{100})$$

Comment: You have the right approach, now simplify the equation :)

Comment: @5xum Thank you very much for your feedback :)

Comment: Oh, so you're using a decimal comma! That is always a bit confusing when one is so used to seeing decimal points. Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. The next step is to simplify the expression. The expression simplifies to

$$\frac{3}{10} - \frac{9}{100} a + \frac{8}{100} b = 0$$

and this simplifies further once you multiply it by $100$ to

$$9a-8b=30$$